# Accessing a MongoDB remotely using Pymongo where Ip filtering is used [requires openvpn - cyberoam unique IP]

Tags: python, mongodb, ubuntu, pymongo, openvpn

I have to access the MongoDB and I can easily access it remotely using `Pymongo` in a `jupyter` notebook when I run the `sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn` in my terminal and then connectiong the Pymongo like:

```
client = MongoClient(host='host_ip',port=port_num)
db = client['db_name']
db.authenticate(name='username',password='password')
```

But how can I do the same when I want to access the DB over a cloud?

I have tried

```
client = MongoClient(host='host_ip',port=port_num,ssl=True,
                     ssl_certfile='UserCertificate.pem',
                     ssl_keyfile='UserPrivateKey.key',)

db = client['db_name']
db.authenticate(name='username',password='password')
```

It throws error after the last line of code while authenticating

```
ServerSelectionTimeoutError: host_ip:port_num: timed out
```

Comment: Is the IP address in a private range?

Comment: yes. I have the login credentials for cyberoam too.

Comment: Private IPs cannot be directly routed over the internet, you will have to use some manner of proxy, address translation, or encapsulation like a VPN

Comment: How do I use that in Google Colab? Any ideas?